# docker compose: Browser can't access to files shared with nginx

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config

I'm learning docker and I need to make a container of nginx and another for php. Apparently it's correct, but I cannot access the files. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if I have a wrong site.conf file.

My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  http:
    hostname: nginx_container
    domainname: mysite.local
    build: ./infrastructure/docker/nginx
    ports:
      - "8085:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src/www:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./src/site.conf://etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    restart: always
    networks:
      - code-network

  php:
    build: ./infrastructure/docker/php
    volumes:
      - ./src/www:/usr/share/nginx/html
    restart: always
    networks:
      - code-network

networks:
    code-network:
        driver: bridge
```

The nginx Dockerfile is:

```
FROM nginx:stable
MAINTAINER foo
```

The php Dockerfile is:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm
MAINTAINER foo
```

The site.conf file is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

and in the src/www path I have an index.html, and index.php and a php-status.php files with the same content:

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

But if I try to access to http://localhost:8085 or http://localhost:8085/index.php I get a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

And if I try a http://mysite.local or http://mysite.local:8085 or http://mysite.local/index.php I get and ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I haven't modified the hosts file, but the objective is reach to the index with the mysite.local, but if I can't reach it with localhost I can't reach it with mysite.local even if I add it to the hosts file.

I've been all day trying to solve it, but I miss something and can't access to the php-info(). Can anybody help me please?

used versions:

- Docker engine 19.03.5
- Docker compose 1.24.1
- Docker machine 0.16.2
- macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: `hostname:` and `domainname:` only affect what the container thinks its own hostname is; they don't affect anything outside the container and setting them has almost no effect.  Nothing you can set in Docker will make a container visible from outside Docker on any particular DNS name.

Comment: @DavidMaze what if I change the server name in the site.conf? I tried also with `server_name mysite.local;` instead of `server_name localhost;` but still can't access with localhost:8085 or mysite.local

Comment: How about trying absolute paths instead of relative paths while declaring volumes?

Comment: @Yuva I use relative paths because project may be moved to another path and it should also work without changing the code paths.